# Advanced Custom Fields format

Tags: wordpress, post

I have a valid code for writte phone number of user in wordpress, but i wish show this numbers like "111 111 111". Someone can help me?

This is my code:

```
<?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; echo get_post_meta($postid, 'telefono_2', true); ?>
<?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; $meta = get_post_meta($postid, 'telefono_3', true);

if($meta != 0) {
  echo " / ".$meta;
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're getting your phone number in `$meta` to display, and that you only need to format it:

```
echo substr($meta, 0, 3) . ' ' . substr($meta, 3, 3) . ' ' . substr($meta, 6, 3);
```

This will show the first three characters, a space, next three, and so on. You could also sanitize to be sure that there are only numbers in your string:

```
$meta = preg_replace('/[^0-9]*/','', $meta);
// ...and then echo as shown above
```

Comment: Don't work for me. Sorry, but really thanks. I'm trying put code in everyplaces and only work in second phone, but duplicate

Comment: I finally put this

    if($meta != 0) {
$meta = preg_replace('/[^0-9]*/','', $meta);
$meta2 = 
substr($meta, 0, 3) . ' ' . substr($meta, 3, 3) . ' ' . substr($meta, 6, 3);
echo " / ".$meta2;

But only works in second phone (telefono_3)